# Combine rows in a groupby by condition in spark

Tags: python, pyspark

Let's say I have  dataframe in spark.
If I do:

```
df.groupby('fruits').count().sort(col('count').desc())
```

I will get the table below

| fruits | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 100 |
| orange | 50 |
| strawberry | 50 |
| another | 50 |
| more | 50 |

How do I combine rows so I get this table instead?

| fruits | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 100 |
| others | 200 |

Hopefully in a way where I pick and choose which values to keep and which to combine into "others"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `when().otherwise()` to update the `fruits` column's values before the aggregation.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('fruits_updated',
               func.when(func.col('fruits') == 'apple', func.col('fruits')).
               otherwise(func.lit('others'))
               ). \
    groupBy('fruits_updated'). \
    agg(func.sum('count').alias('count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# turn all fruits names, except "apple"
df.loc[df.fruit != "apple", "fruit"] = "others"

#group by fruit name and sum the counts
df.groupby(['fruit']).sum()
```

Comment: This is actually for pandas. But a pyspark equivalent is easy enough